# What is the difference between 覺得 and 想？

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

I have hard time making clear distinction between 覺得 and 想.

According to the dictionary:.
- 想：to think / to believe / to suppose / to wish / to want / to miss (feel wistful about the absence of sb or sth).
- 覺得：to think / to feel.

What confuses me is the meaning of "to think".  It is often overused to express many things: personal opinion, judgement, feelings...

Note:.
I understand  the use of 想 to express missing something or someone, ex: 我很想媽媽。

Comment: see long lists of dictionary examples for either, e.g. in bkrs, 想 and 觉得 are not considered synonyms, bkrs: **想** ：syn。相关: 念, 怀念, 思, 思念, 思量, 想念, 感念, 感怀, 朝思暮想, 眷念, 眷恋, 纪念 **觉得** ：syn.同义①: 感到, 感觉 同义②: 认为, 以为
相关: 认为, 以为, 道, 看, 当, **认为**  and **觉得** are close in meaning, see discussion of these on the web

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you learned from dictionaries, 想 and 覺得 have meanings that are not overlapped.

When it comes to the overlapped meaning 'think', the different between 想 and 覺得 are as below:

"我[想]机会不是很大" - "I [think] the chance is not great" (thinking mainly base on imagination/ **judgment**; mostly a prediction)

"我[覺得]机会不是很大" - "I [think] the chance is not great" (thinking mainly base on **feeling**; mostly a hint/ feeling)

Both '想' and  '覺得' describe 'expressing opinion' , but with different base. If you what  to emphasize the opinion is base on judgment after some consideration, you should use '想'; If you what  to emphasize the opinion is base on a hint or some feeling, you should use '覺得'

More example:

我(想)德國隊會赢 - in your judgment, team Germany will win (*base on the past record and the skill level gap between the two teams*)

我(覺得)德國隊會赢 - you personally feel Germany will win (*just a hint, because they seem like a winner*)

Comment: Thanks a lot @tang-ho for the explanations. Now it is much more clear.

Answer (score -1):

just  remember "觉得" means  "to feel" , not "to think" in the dictionary you use